# Up and down slide dropdown in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

[image]

```css
.main ul {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  overflow:hidden
}
.main a {
margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="#">Up </a>
  <ul>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
     <li>dropdown 1</li> 
     <li>dropdown 1</li>
      <li>dropdown 1</li>
       <li>dropdown 1</li>
        <li>dropdown 1</li>
         <li>dropdown 1</li>
          <li>dropdown 1</li>
           <li>dropdown 1</li>
            <li>dropdown 1</li>
             <li>dropdown 1</li>
              <li>dropdown 1</li>
  </ul>
  
   <a href="#">Down </a>
</div>
```

Now i want if i click up button then list item should be slide up and if i click down button the list item should going down. How can i do this by vue js please anyone help me.

Comment: Check out the [transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect that you were hoping to achieve? Liberal use of `querySelector`, `querySelectorAll` and various sibling selectors make this a relatively straight forward task.

```js
// assign event handler to each hyperlink which themselves have a dataset attribute to aid identification
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-dir]').forEach( a=>a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // the css class that will be assigned to indicate selected item
    const cn='active';

    let ul=this.parentNode.querySelector('ul');
    let col=Array.from( ul.querySelectorAll('li') );
    
    // prevent highlist disappearing
    if( ( ul.querySelector('li.active')==ul.lastElementChild && this.dataset.dir=='down' ) || ( ul.querySelector('li.active')==ul.firstElementChild && this.dataset.dir=='up' ) )return false;


    // If no active element is found, make the first LI active.
    if( !ul.querySelector('li.active') )ul.firstElementChild.classList.add( cn );
    else{
        // otherwise process all LI elements until we find the active element
        col.some( li=>{
            if( li.classList.contains(cn) ){
                // clear an other instances of the active class
                col.forEach(n=>n.classList.remove(cn));
                    
                // highlight appropriate previous/next LI element
                switch( this.dataset.dir ){
                    case 'up':
                        if( li.previousElementSibling!=null && li.previousElementSibling.tagName=='LI' )li.previousElementSibling.classList.add(cn)
                    break;
                    case 'down':
                        if( li.nextElementSibling!=null && li.nextElementSibling.tagName=='LI' )li.nextElementSibling.classList.add(cn);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

```css
.main ul {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style:none inside;
}
.main a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
li{
  padding:0.25rem;background:whitesmoke;
}
.active{
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="#" data-dir='up'>Up</a>
  <ul>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li> 
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
    <li>dropdown 1</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-dir='down'>Down</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I believe the OP wants to know how to do it in Vue

Comment: Alas I read that after I had written the above...

Answer (score 0):

@Professor Abronsius has a good solution using pure Javascript but if you want to do this in Vue you'll need to have your times in your `data` object and a scoped variable to keep track of which item is selected.

To expand on this you'd probably want to dynamically update your times array as the user cycled through them.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected:2,
    times: [
      "11:00am",
      "10:00am",
      "9:00am",
      "8:00am",
      "7:00am",
      "6:00am"
    ]  
  },
  methods: {
    up: function(){
        this.selected--;
    },
    down: function(){
        this.selected++;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
width:100px;
}
li.active {
background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Times:</h2>
  <span v-on:click="up">Up</span>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(time, index) in times" :class="{ active : selected == index}">
      {{time}}
     </li>
   </ul>
   <span v-on:click="down">Down</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But it is not sliding

Comment: You need to be clearer with what you’re trying to achieve. Which part is sliding?

Comment: I want, if down click then number list i mean li tag should change and it move to up and next li tag move
exmple i have total 10 "li" tag i want to show first 4 "li" tag if i click down button then 5 no "li" tag come and 1 no "li" tag move top and its not showing, if i click top button then 5 no "li" tag going down and 1no "li tag " come back . I hope you understand my problem thank you

Comment: I’d have a look at the transitions docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html. The approach would vary depending on whether the whole list moves and the highlight bar stays in the same place, or if the highlight bar moves

Comment: I need to  the whole list moves not only highlighted .